# Django. No module named

Tags: python, django, rest

Пытаюсь сделать API на Django. Использую rest framework (делаю по туториалу). После запуска (runserver) выдает ошибку:

> File \apifin\apifin\urls.py
>
> from apifin.get_data import views
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apifin.get_data'

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Файл urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from apifin.get_data import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.FinanceViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

models.py приложения get_data

```
from django.db import models

class Finance(models.Model):
    ID = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    TICKER = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    PER = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    DATE = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    TIME = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    OPEN = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    HIGH = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LOW = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    CLOSE = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    VOL = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

serializers.py приложения get_data

```
from .models import Finance
from rest_framework import serializers

class FinanceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Finance
        fields = ['TICKER', 'PER', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'OPEN', 'HIGH', 'LOW', 'CLOSE', 'VOL']
```

views.py приложения get_data

```
from .models import Finance
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from apifin.get_data.serializers import FinanceSerializer

class FinanceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Finance.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FinanceSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

Фрагмент файла settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'get_data.apps.GetDataConfig',
]
```

[image: Фото]

Comment: Покажите расположение всех этих файлов и каталогов

Comment: @andreymal добавил фото

Comment: У вас модуль `get_data` находится не внутри модуля `apifin`, поэтому питон и не может найти его внутри `apifin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно указывать путь от файла **manage.py**.

Для `views`, например:

```
from get_data.serializers import FinanceSerializer
```